# How to use a Variable (with $) in a FilePath to start cURL?

Tags: powershell, variables, curl, path, exe

this is my current situation. Im trying to hold it short, so please dont ask why i made some things like this:

Im in this path already in: C:\cURL

This works fine: `PS C:\cURL> & '.\Extern$\Curl\bin\curl.exe'`
-> Like this Im in the curl.exe and i can use it.

But because of some reasons I need to put " .\Extern$ " into a variable, e.g. $Extern
Means:

```
PS C:\cURL>$Extern = ".\Extern$"
```

So normally this should also work right?

`PS C:\cURL> & '$Extern\Curl\bin\curl.exe'`

Sadly it doesnt.

To sum up: My aim is to replace this path part `.\Extern$` with a variable like `$Extern or $path`

Thanks for helping!

Comment: single qoutes `'$code'`  are literal. You will need to use double `"$code"`

Comment: Also best to edit your Q to show how you are trying to use this, and actual error messages that indicate it isn't working. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is single quotes `'`. They are literal.

```
$Name = "TestName"
'$Name'
```

Will return

```
$Name
```

While double quotes `"` will allow you to display the variable.

```
$Name = "TestName"
"$Name"
```

Will return

```
TestName
```

For your example

```
$Extern = ".\Extern$"
& "$Extern\Curl\bin\curl.exe"
```

Should run .\Extern$\Curl\bin\curl.exe

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what I need to change so I can run curl.exe with a Variable in the path? I already tried your way before, didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: It says that the module $Extern" couldnt be loaded.

Comment: try what i posted if that doesnt work. Paste exactly what you have in powershell